# Analytic Expression for special integral

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

I want to calculate
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\arctan{2t}}{e^{2\pi t}+1} \, {\rm d}t
$$
and am wondering if there at all is an analytical expression for the result.
I haven't tried much so far, but expressing the denominator as the geometric series and then substituting $z=2\pi t (n+1)$. Equivalently I get
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{{\rm si}\left(\pi(n+1)\right)}{2\pi (n+1)}
$$
where
$$
{\rm si}(x) = -\int_{x}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(t)}{t} \, {\rm d}t
$$
is the shifted ${\rm Si}(x)$ function. The value is approximately $0.03618247146$, in fact I know from comparison with something else that it is exactly $\frac{\ln \pi -1}{4}$, but there should be some (direct) derivation, or?

Thanks for your input if you have any.

Edit: I tried to follow your instructions, but am now stuck.
So I wrote
$$
{\cal L}^{-1} \left(\frac{\psi(t)-\psi(1)}{t-1}\right)(s) =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-sn}}{n+1} = e^s \int_s^\infty \frac{{\rm d}x}{e^{x}-1}
$$
and taking the Laplace-transform
\begin{align}
\psi(t) &= \psi(1) + (t-1)\int_0^\infty {\rm d}s \, e^{-s(t-1)} \int_s^\infty \frac{{\rm d}x}{e^{x}-1} \\
&= \psi(1) + (t-1) \int_0^\infty {\rm d}x \int_{0}^{x} {\rm d}s \, \frac{e^{-s(t-1)}}{e^{x}-1} \\
&= \psi(1) + \int_{0}^{\infty} {\rm d}x \, \frac{1-e^{-x(t-1)}}{e^x-1} \tag{1} \\
&= -\frac{1}{t} + \psi(1) + \int_0^\infty {\rm d}x \, \frac{1-e^{-tx}}{e^x-1} \tag{2} \\
&= \dots \\
&=-\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{t+k} + \psi(1) + \int_0^\infty {\rm d}x \, \frac{1-e^{-(t+n)x}}{e^x-1} \\
&\stackrel{(\rm{2})}{=} -\frac{1}{2t} + \ln(t) - \int_0^\infty {\rm d}x \, \left\{ \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{e^x-1}\right\} e^{-tx} \tag{Binet 1}
\end{align}
where $\psi(1)=-\gamma$.

Now we integrate over $t$ from $1$ to $y$ yielding
$$
\ln \Gamma(y) \stackrel{({\rm 1})}{=} \psi(1)\,(y-1) + \int_0^\infty {\rm d}x \, \frac{y-1+\frac{e^{-x(y-1)}-1}{x}}{e^x-1}
$$
but what now? Substitute?

Comment: The given integral immediately recalls Binet's second log-Gamma formula: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsLogGammaFormulas.html

Comment: You essentially got Binet's first formula. Now you have to rearrange it into $$ \psi(z) = \log(z)-\frac{1}{2z}+C-2\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{t\,dt}{(z^2+t^2)(e^{2\pi t}-1)}$$ then integrate with respect to $z$.

Comment: As far as I see from your notation, you are using a result from p.250 Whittaker & Watson where a variant of Euler-Maclaurin summation formula is used.
I haven't been able to convert $({\rm Binet 1})$ by simple rearrangement to $({\rm Binet 2})$ though.

Comment: Also see difference of sum and integral with same argument

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By considering that $\frac{1}{z+1}= \frac{1}{z-1}-\frac{2}{z^2-1}$ and that, by [Binet's second $\log\Gamma$ formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsLogGammaFormulas.html),
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\arctan\frac{t}{z}}{e^{2\pi t}-1}\,dt = \frac{1}{2}\left[\log\Gamma(z)-\left(z-\tfrac{1}{2}\right)\log z+z-\log\sqrt{2\pi}\right]\tag{Binet} $$
we get
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\arctan(2t)}{e^{2\pi t}-1}\,dt = \frac{1-\log 2}{4}$$
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{2\arctan(2t)}{e^{4\pi t}-1}\,dt =\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\arctan(t)}{e^{2\pi t}-1}\,dt = \frac{2-\log(2\pi)}{4}$$
and the given integral equals $\color{red}{\frac{-1+\log\pi}{4}}$ as suspected.

---

I am adding a brief sketch of the proof of $(\text{Binet})$, since the linked Wikipedia page appears to miss it. By applying the (inverse) Laplace transform to the well-known identity
$$ \frac{\psi(a)-\psi(b)}{a-b}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(n+a)(n+b)} $$
one gets an integral representation for the Digamma function. A further step of integration through Fubini's theorem leads to [an integral representation for $\log\Gamma$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogGammaFunction.html), which can be easily rearranged into $(\text{Binet})$.

Comment: I tried to follow your instructions. See edit.